# Traveler's Salat: When the reduction should be started?

Tags: salat, travelling, salat-al-qasr

Suppose I am on a journey to more than the minimum distance (three manzils or 77 km) to be considered as Musafir (Traveler) with a intention of staying less than 15 days.

- When does the Qasr Salah comes to consideration? Immediately after the journey has begun, or whenever 77km is traveled?
- Should I participate Jamat of Salat or prefer to perform salat alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Hanafi school of fiqh, you become a traveller once you are out of your home town. You should do Qasr for all Salahs after this point until unless you have arrived back or have firmly decided to stay at destination for over 15 days (counting from the day you make the intention).

Joining a jamat is always better.

For Maghrib and Fajr prayers you can join jamats without any confusions as to how many rakats you will have to do. Just make the intention of praying Qasr Salah.

For the rest any additional rakats that you will perform would be considered as Nafil (voluntary).

For further detail, refer to Shaykh Abu Usamah's fatwa [here](http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=3079&CATE=165).