# who is a Musafir?

Tags: source-identification, terminology

Musafir is a traveler, but after covering how much distance is a person called Musafir? I've been searching for this everywhere but the distance varies everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traveler's Salat: When the reduction should be started?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/travelers-salat-when-the-reduction-should-be-started)

Answer (score 3):

Assalam-O-Alaykoum

The most known response is 80 km, which is 49.70 Miles.

And Allah knows better.

Comment: I think one important thing is missing a mussafir is not back home on the same day!

Answer (score 1):

A musafir is the one who is travelling in a distance that is equal or exceeds two marhalah (apprx. 86 ~ 90 km) in one way direction.

If lets say a town is 45km and he travelled forth and back, which is 90km, that cannot be considered as a musafir.

If you are talking about the rukhsah on the Salaah (for example shortening zhuhr and asr from 4rakaat to 2 rakaat) a person must be musafir and the purposes of the journey must not something that is sinful.

Wallahu a'lam

Comment: I think one important thing is missing a mussafir is not back home on the same day!