# What rules apply when fasting for Ramadan while traveling through different time zones?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, travelling

I've read [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/15000/11672) about whether one should fast in case of long distance travelling.

Nevertheless a case that is not mentioned in the answer is what happens if one is travelling between different time zones. Not that much the time zones are the issue, but more the fact that the sun is shining at different time intervals at the different locations.

Say for instance you travel from *New York* to *London*. If the plane takes of at 8 AM local time, then the plane arrives in *London* at 8 PM local time. But it took the plane only 7 hours to do that. As a result one has "virtually" shortened the day. The opposite can also happen: a plane from *London* to *New York* virtually makes the day longer.

My question is what should happen to the fasting hours in that case. Should one use the local ones (and thus fast longer on a day one travels from London to New York), or should one stick to the context of the begin/end of the voyage?

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the Quran is to start the fast at dawn and to break it at sunset, so scholars derive that the actual duration in hours is irrelevant and one should act according to what one observes in the place they are at that point in time.

> [Quran 2:187](https://quran.com/2/187) ... And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn
>   becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night]. Then
>   complete the fast until the night (sunset) ...

For further reference see fatwa [here](https://islamqa.info/en/38007).